# Cortex-M3 SysTick double interrupt

Tags: nested, cortex-m, rtos, interrupted-exception, stm32f1

I'm creating a rtos system, with system tick (1ms) for real-time and trigger pendsv-which used for switch task. Priority of systick and pendsv same as 0 (group = 16; <SCB.AIRCR.PRIGROUP = 0b011>). PendSv also trigger by <SCB.ICSR.PENDSVSET = 1> when current task is sleep.
Sometime, PendSV and SysTick occurs at the same time, and SysTick is executed first, then PendSv. But after PendSV executed, SysTick occurs again.
I was tried by change priority, and clear <SCB.ICSR.PENDSTCLR = 1> in system tick handle, nothing changed.
Do you know why, and how to fix that?
[logic_analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFlv6.png)

asm code:

```
//#define USING_PUSH_POP

  EXTERN GPIOA_BITBAND

  EXTERN RTOS_GetCurrentCPU                     //CPU_TypeDef* RTOS_GetCurrentCPU();
  EXTERN RTOS_GetNextCPU                        //CPU_TypeDef* RTOS_GetNextCPU();

  PUBLIC PendSV_Handler
  PUBLIC RTOS_ASM_Begin                         //void RTOS_ASM_ASM_Begin(CPU_TypeDef* CPU);
  
  SECTION rtos_function:CODE
  PendSV_Handler:
  //PUSH in SP when interrupt
  //Here - R0 - R1 - R2 - R3 - R12 - BACK_LR - BACK_PC - EAPSR
  PUSH          {LR}
  
  LDR.W         R0, =GPIOA_BITBAND   //(1)
  MOV           R1, #1
  STR           R1, [R0, #0x180]
  
  
  BL            RTOS_GetCurrentCPU
  CMP           R0, #0
  BEQ           BREAK                           //if (NULL): back to current task
  BL            RTOS_ASM_SaveCurrentCPU

  BL            RTOS_GetNextCPU
  CMP           R0, #0
  BEQ           BREAK                           //if (NULL): back to current task
  B             RTOS_ASM_SwitchNextCPU
BREAK:
  POP           {PC}
//===================================
  RTOS_ASM_Begin:                               //R0: CPU_TypeDef* MainCPU
  PUSH          {R1, LR}
  STR           LR , [R0, #28]
  STR           R1 , [R0, #24]
  ADDS          R1 , R0, #24
  MOV           SP , R1
  BL            RTOS_ASM_SaveCurrentCPU  
  POP           {R1, PC}
//===================================
  RTOS_ASM_SaveCurrentCPU:                      //R0: CPU_TypeDef* CurrentCPU
#ifdef USING_PUSH_POP
  MOVS          R1 , SP
  STR           SP , [R0, #(4 * 16)]
  ADDS          R0 , R0, #(4 * 16)
  MOVS          SP , R0
  PUSH          {R4-R11}
  MOVS          SP , R1
#else
  STR           R4 , [R0, #(4 * 8 )]
  STR           R5 , [R0, #(4 * 9 )]
  STR           R6 , [R0, #(4 * 10)]
  STR           R7 , [R0, #(4 * 11)]
  STR           R8 , [R0, #(4 * 12)]
  STR           R9 , [R0, #(4 * 13)]
  STR           R10, [R0, #(4 * 14)]
  STR           R11, [R0, #(4 * 15)]
  STR           SP , [R0, #(4 * 16)]  
#endif
  BX            LR
//===================================
  RTOS_ASM_SwitchNextCPU:                       //R0: CPU_TypeDef* NextCPU
#ifdef USING_PUSH_POP
  ADDS          R1 , R0, #(4 * 8)
  MOVS          SP , R1
  POP           {R4-R11}
  LDR           SP , [R0, #(4 * 16)]
#else
  LDR           R4 , [R0, #(4 * 8 )]
  LDR           R5 , [R0, #(4 * 9 )]
  LDR           R6 , [R0, #(4 * 10)]
  LDR           R7 , [R0, #(4 * 11)]
  LDR           R8 , [R0, #(4 * 12)]
  LDR           R9 , [R0, #(4 * 13)]
  LDR           R10, [R0, #(4 * 14)]
  LDR           R11, [R0, #(4 * 15)]
  LDR           SP , [R0, #(4 * 16)]
#endif

  LDR.W         R0, =GPIOA_BITBAND   //(2)
  MOV           R1, #0
  STR           R1, [R0, #0x180]

  POP           {PC}  
//===================================
  END
```

system tick handle:

```
void SysTick_Handler()
{
  GPIOB_BITBAND.ODR._10 ^= 1;   //(3)
  System.MsTick++;
  if (TaskManager.Running)
    RTOS_SWITCH_TRIGGER();
  //SCB.ICSR.REG = BIT25;
  SCB.ICSR.BITS.PENDSTCLR = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution now is using SVC instead of PendSV